# As3: XML parsing just doesn't want to work

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, tile

I am using this code:

```
private function loadLevel(xml:Class):void
{
    var rawData:ByteArray = new xml;
    var dataString:String = rawData.readUTFBytes(rawData.length);
    var xmlData:XML = new XML(dataString);

    var dataList:XMLList;
    var dataElement:XML;

    dataList = xmlData.Tiles.tile;

    for each(dataElement in dataList)
    {
        trace("HI");
        _tiles.setTile(int(dataElement.@x) / 120, int(dataElement.@y) / 120, int(dataElement.@tx) / 120);
    }
}
```

But I get no trace!!

This is the tmx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="16" height="9" tilewidth="120"     tileheight="120">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="u" tilewidth="120" tileheight="120">
  <image source="../assets/tileset1.png" width="360" height="120"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Tiles" width="16" height="9">
  <data>
   <tile gid="2"/>
   <tile gid="2"/>
   blablabla repeat
  </data>
 </layer>
 <objectgroup name="Spawn" width="16" height="9">
  <object x="120" y="892" width="122" height="28"/>
  <object x="2222" y="-244"/>
 </objectgroup>
</map>
```

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek0HLk6wBmQ 
Why am I not receiving a trace statement? It just doesn't work

Comment: And where is `Tiles`in xml that you have provided? If you need `tile` - `xmlData.layer.data.tile`

Comment: where it says <layer name="Tiles" width="16" height="9">

Answer (score 1):

Are you want access `<layer name="Tiles" width="16" height="9">` element?

if right, try this

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML(dataString);

var name:String = xmlData.layer.@name;
var width:int = xmlData.layer.@width;
var height:int = xmlData.layer.@height;
```

if you want access this elements

```
<tile gid="2"/>
<tile gid="2"/>
```

try this

```
for each(var element:XML in xmlData.layer.data.tile)
{
     trace(element.@gid);
}
```

if you want access this elements. first matching the same elements as second node add a width and height attribute.

```
<object x="120" y="892" width="122" height="28"/>
<object x="2222" y="-244" widht="200" height"400"/>
```

And try this

```
for each(var element:XML in xmlData.objectgroup.object)
{
   trace("x: " + element.@x + " y: " + element.@y + " width: " + element.@width + " height: " + element.@height);
}
```

This tutorial is Actionscript 3.0 E4X(ECMA for XML) syntax to understand that will help you.

---

## Edited

I talk to your problem. see the below.

1. `dataList = xmlData.Tiles.tile;` is wrong because xml not have `Tiles` node.
2. see a xml, `tile` node is only access as this syntax: `xmlData.layer.data.tile`. however, the you have a two tile node so xmlData.layer.data.tile return array. so first tile node is xmlData.layer.data.tile[0] and second tile node is xmlData.layer.data.tile[1].
3. `tile` node not have any `x`, `y`, `tx` attribute. is only have a `object` node. but `tx` is not anywhere appeared.

p.s: You must create a xml as same in the video... the tutorial algorithm is based on specified xml in video. but, i supposed before the solve this problem. you must understand AS3.0 E4X.

E4X tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-xml-basix--active-2908
http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

Comment: Awesome, I'm just a bit confused since there are some new variables in your answer. If I want to put the tiles with the number 1 in a grid, like this for example: _tiles.setTile(int(dataElement.@x) / 120, int(dataElement.@y) / 120, int(dataElement.@tx) / 120); -- but with the number 1 tiles only, how would I type it?

Comment: I think your XML you need to be a little more refined. Now that the structure is not intuitive. what's the mean `setTile` function each arguments where is `tx` attribute in XML?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it. If you check this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek0HLk6wBmQ @ 10:11 - then you will see what is going on. I'm following that tutorial. But I am not using OGMO editor. I am using TILED.

Comment: I see that. ok, Plz upload a you're really XML file. your XML is spaghetti. He's video already have a Perfectly XML. but you not have a any `tx`, `ty` attribute.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't seem to export an XML file like that.. How do we adjust the code to the type of XML TIled produces?

Comment: ok... are you have a source file url link? plz let me know. i'll help you.

Comment: Source file of what? The XML?

Comment: Yeah. I just edited out some of the    <tile gid="2"/> lines. There were a lot of them. And some <tile gid="1"/> too

Comment: give me a you're full .fla file or flash builder source code link. i'll help you.

Comment: There are a lot of files, I have no idea how ot send it all. I am using flashdevelop. Can't we fix it by just changing some line in the code I posted??

Comment: Hi again. I tried changing the code into this:    dataList = xmlData.layer.data.Tiles.tile;
   
   for each(dataElement in dataList)
   {
    trace("HI");
                        }

But I get no trace.. what am I doing wrong? I'm confused

Comment: See the my edited answer... you're big mistaken... your not understand tutorial video... you're xml is wrong..

Comment: But TILED can't export the same type of xml as in the video.. So what am I supposed to do??

Comment: you must create a xml as same in the video... what's the mean export??? the tutorial algorithm is based on specified xml in video.

Comment: I downloaded OGMO, but it doesn't even create the same type of xml!! I have no idea what to do